# Jquery Mouseover doesn't work IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mouseover

I need to show and image over another image when mouseover, this is a kind of menu. This works in chrome and firefox. Any Idea? Here comes the come

```
<div id="button1OverStyle" class="buttonOverStyle" onclick="changeFrame('main/main.html')" >
<img id="button1OverStyleImage" src="images/button_home.png" height="24" width="46" />
```

```
<script>      
  $('#button1OverStyle').hover(function(e) {
    showTittle('button1OverStyleImage');  });
  $('#button1OverStyle').mouseleave(function(e) {
    hideTittle('button1OverStyleImage');});
  $('#button2OverStyle').mouseover(function(e) {
    showTittle('button2OverStyleImage'); });
  $('#button2OverStyle').mouseleave(function(e) {
    hideTittle('button2OverStyleImage'); });      
</script>
```

---

I found where to find it. And This is the problem

in this line

```
<div id="button1OverStyle" class="buttonOverStyle" onclick="changeFrame('main/main.html')" >
            <img id="button1OverStyleImage" src="images/button_home.png" height="24" width="46" />
        </div>
```

Here Are the CSS

```
.buttonOverStyle{   position:absolute;  cursor:pointer;     z-index:1000;   height:24px;}  .buttonOverStyle img {   display:none;}
```

The problem is that if the image is not display the internet explorer does not recognize the div, so it can't make the "mouseenter" or "mouseover".

**ANY IDEA??????**

Comment: Is your 'showTittle' function called ? If so, show us the code of this function.

Comment: Did you mean to spell it 'showTitle' instead of tittle?

Comment: function showTittle(id){
   $('#'+id).fadeIn(200);
  }
  
  function hideTittle(id){
   $('#'+id).fadeOut(200);
  }

Comment: it works in other like chrome, but not in IE

Comment: try wrapping your code inside a document.ready function so it waits until the dom is ready before trying to bind the events `$(function()` or `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: still the same, this is weird.

Comment: with the ready function it stop working in firefox

Answer (score 1):

Try [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/):

> The mouseenter JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer.
>   Because of the event's general utility, jQuery simulates this event so
>   that it can be used regardless of browser. This event is sent to an
>   element when the mouse pointer enters the element. Any HTML element
>   can receive this event.

**HTML**

```
<div>test</div>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$("div").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
$("div").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fBM4j/)**

You could also try [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Probably a few minor things adding up this, the mouse event included. I'll keep taking a look and see if anything else jumps out at me.

Comment: if have an height and width, because without it, it doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: Is the div wrapped around the image tag and closed? http://jsfiddle.net/Max7V/3/ From your code above it doesn't seem like that div is being closed which could cause an issue.

Comment: double check, it's wrapped 
<div id="button1OverStyle" class="buttonOverStyle" onclick="changeFrame('main/main.html')" ><img id="button1OverStyleImage" src="images/button_home.png" height="24" width="46" /></div>

Comment: y can't put all the html together! maybe there is an other thing wrong

Comment: What version of IE is giving you problems?

Comment: Putting your code into jsfiddle is working for me in IE9 as far as I can tell: http://jsfiddle.net/pELQg/4/

Comment: I noticed that in the code you posted, `$("button1OverStyle").` is missing a `#`; should be `$("#button1OverStyle").` ... http://jsfiddle.net/pELQg/7/

Comment: still nothing! it's making me crazy!

Comment: the problem is other! when the image is display none, in explorer cant do the hover

Comment: Instead of `display:none` you could try `visibility:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Solution!

I make it all in Css but with opacity

```
.buttonOverStyle img {
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=10)";
filter: alpha(opacity=10);
opacity: .1;}


.buttonOverStyle img:hover {
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=90)";
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
opacity: .9;}
```

this works for me