# Script Errors in IE 8 on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm having a problem that is only occurring in IE 8 and earlier. I am not encountering any problems in any other browsers.

I am using the maphighlight plugin to activate certain areas of the map. This occurs when either the map area or the name of the area is selected from the list below. A sidebar is supposed to appear and disappear when hovering onto and off of the map area. Everything seems to be working fine when hovering on, but when I hover off I get script error messages. `Unknown runtime error, Line: 162 Char: 4` in `jquery.maphilight.js`. The map space stays lit permanently until refreshing the page afterwards.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, as I am nearing the end of my expertise on the subject.

[My Site](http://www.supportexcellence.org/naming)

Map:

```
$(function() {
    $('.map').maphilight();

        $('#np1-link').mouseover(function(e) {
            $('#np1').mouseover();
        }).mouseout(function(e) {
            $('#np1').mouseout();
        }).click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
    });
```

Hover Over:

```
function hovIn() {
    var areaID = $(this).attr('id');
    if (areaID == 'np1') {
        $('#sidebar_newpavilion').show();
    }
```

Hover Out:

```
function hovOut() {
    $('#sidebar_newpavilion').hide();
}

$('map area').hover(hovIn, hovOut);
```

**UPDATE:**

This is where it is saying the run time error is occuring, when the canvas is supposed to be cleared. Any reason why this wouldn't work in IE8?

```
        clear_canvas = function(canvas) {
        // jquery1.8 + ie7 
        var $html = $("<div>" + canvas.innerHTML + "</div>");
        $html.children('[name=highlighted]').remove();
        canvas.innerHTML = $html.html();
    };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787373/jquery-mouseover-doesnt-work-ie

Comment: I just tried a few of the steps suggested in that topic with no luck, and using CSS isn't an option.

Comment: IE seems to have issues with elements that are not yet visible. You'll need a way to work around that. You may add css properties using javascript as well. That is what the libraries are also doing.

Comment: Can you reiterate? It seems that the problem only occurs when I am turning OFF elements by hovering off of them. Is this the wrong way of looking at it?

Comment: Yes, so that seems to be the problem. You could use opacity (ie. make it 0) instead of turning the visibility off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

Here is the simple solution by converting double quote to single quote.

```
    clear_canvas = function(canvas) {
        // jquery1.8 + ie7 
        var $html = $("<div>" + canvas.innerHTML + "</div>");
        $html.children('[name=highlighted]').remove();
        canvas.innerHTML = $html.html().replace("\"","'");
    };
```